# Implementation of strstr fails with the last word

Tags: c, strstr

I have the following implementation of strstr

**NOTE:** This code is not mine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

char *fast_strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle)
{
    if (!*needle) // Empty needle.
        return (char *) haystack;

    const char    needle_first  = *needle;

    // Runs strchr() on the first section of the haystack as it has a lower
    // algorithmic complexity for discarding the first non-matching characters.
    haystack = strchr(haystack, needle_first);
    if (!haystack) // First character of needle is not in the haystack.
        return NULL;

    // First characters of haystack and needle are the same now. Both are
    // guaranteed to be at least one character long.
    // Now computes the sum of the first needle_len characters of haystack
    // minus the sum of characters values of needle.

    const char   *i_haystack = haystack + 1,
                  *i_needle   = needle   + 1;

    unsigned int  sums_diff = *haystack;
    bool          identical = true;

    while (*i_haystack && *i_needle)
    {
        sums_diff += *i_haystack;
        sums_diff -= *i_needle;
        identical &= *i_haystack++ == *i_needle++;
    }

    // i_haystack now references the (needle_len + 1)-th character.

    if (*i_needle) // haystack is smaller than needle.
        return NULL;
    else if (identical)
        return (char *) haystack;

    size_t needle_len = i_needle - needle;
    size_t needle_len_1 = needle_len - 1;

    // Loops for the remaining of the haystack, updating the sum iteratively.
    const char *sub_start;
    for (sub_start = haystack; *i_haystack; i_haystack++)
    {
        sums_diff -= *sub_start++;
        sums_diff += *i_haystack;

        // Since the sum of the characters is already known to be equal at that
        // point, it is enough to check just needle_len-1 characters for
        // equality.
        if (
            sums_diff == 0
            && needle_first == *sub_start // Avoids some calls to memcmp.
            && memcmp(sub_start, needle, needle_len_1) == 0
        )
            return (char *) sub_start;
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    char s[] = "this is a test";
    char s2[] = "test";

    if(fast_strstr(s, s2) != NULL)
        puts("YES!");
    else
        puts("NOT!");

    return 0;
}
```

This gives an incorrect output with the current entry, where is **NOT!** instead **YES!**. This problem occurs only with the last word but the strange thing is that it works it with other strings, any idea why this happens?

Comment: General warning: Casting away the `const` for the result is a bad idea actually. What if `*haystack` is read-only memory? Leave the cast to the caller, as that should know if it is safe or not. There are also quite some issues with signed vs. unsigned. Note that `char` can be either for an implementation (and the major ones: ARM (unsigned) and x86 (signed, at least gcc-Linux-x64) do not use the same.

Comment: @Olaf it has the same behavior and signature as `strstr`, for what that's worth. How does the signedness of char have an impact on this code?

Comment: @Olaf: That's part of the signature of the function being implemented, not something you get to choose. As you can see the converted pointer is not being used to write. It's being returned so that callers that use `strstr` on writable strings to determine where to write can work properly. This is a standard idiom and there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @Tony: Regardless of whether it works, `fast_strstr` is a serious misnomer. This is a very slow approach to `strstr`, not a fast one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code fails if first `char` of needle matches a `char` in the haystack, but the rest does not.
Try `fast_strstr("zhis is a test", "test")`

Instead of the last `return NULL;`, code needs to try the rest of the haystack *after* the first matching letter.  A recursive solution follows, but certainly a loop within the function could be had.

```
return fast_strstr(haystack+1, needle);  // --> YES!
// return NULL;
```

Code may be fast on some input, but appears to be O(n*n)

Comment: You are too fast for your own good. I had it sorted, and I was just working on the best way to keep stepping down haystack. I was working on a loop, but I like the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

`sum_diff` should be initialized to 0, since they matched at the first character there is no initial difference.
If you run this in GDB you will find `sum_diff = 116` (which is the ASCII value of `'t'`.) when it returns instead of 0.

```
 unsigned int  sums_diff = 0; // *haystack - *needle (which is 0)
```

This bug causes it to fail for any haystack where the first character of needle appears earlier in the string and doesn't match completely as this is when you go into the `for` loop and rely on `sum_diff`.